# ¿Se puede utilizar el selector [name=] con varios names al mismo tiempo?

Tags: jquery

Tengo varios radios que utilizan la misma función con lo cual utilizo el selector de esta manera `_$('input[name=radio1]')` pero la cuestión es si puedo simplificar más el selector al nivel de colocar todos los nombres dentro del selector base, me explico, dejarlo así:

```
_$('input[name=radio1|radio2|radio3]')
```

Pero no encontre información al respecto, sería muy útil así y no tenerlo de esta manera:

```
_$('input[name=radio2] input[name=radio2] input[name=radio3]')
```

No se si exista la manera que expongo pero espero que haya una solución más factible, aaah por cierto, solo utilizo un número limitado de radios de los que verdaderamente hay.

PD: Utilizo el "var _$ = jQuery.noConflict();" porque utilizo otros scripts que utilizan el "$".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En este caso podrias utilizar:

```
_$('input[name^="radio"]');
```

Que selecciona todos los inputs con `name` que empieze con "radio".

Comment: El nombre "radio#" fue un ejemplo a drede y bueno, los radios que tengo, todos se llaman diferente, además los utilizo para otras cosas por lo cual y teniendo una función que hace lo mismo para estos grupos de radios, pensé que habría esa manera de agruparlos todos en una misma línea, aunque el dato lo apuntaré cuando realice otros grupos de radios sin que se llamen diferentes.

Comment: Si quieres agrupar todos los radios entonces podrias usar `type` en lugar de `name`.  Ahora si tienes diferentes grupos de radios especificos que quieres agrupar, quizas sea mejor que agregues una clase en comun para referirte a dichos grupos.

Answer (score 6):

Los [selectores por atributos (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo) tienen las siguientes opciones:

> ### [attr]
>
> Selecciona los elementos que tienen el atributo attr.
>
> ### [attr=value]
>
> Selecciona los elementos cuyo atributo attr tenga exactamente el valor
>   value.
>
> ### [attr~=value]
>
> Selecciona los elementos cuyo atributo attr tenga por valor una lista
>   de palabras separadas por espacios, una de las cuales sea value.
>
> ### [attr|=value]
>
> Selecciona los elementos cuyo atributo attr tenga exactamente el valor
>   value o empiece por value seguido de un guión - (U+002D). Se puede
>   usar para coincidencias de subcódigos en otros idiomas.
>
> ### [attr^=value]
>
> Selecciona los elementos cuyo atributo attr tenga un valor prefijado 
>   por value.
>
> ### [attr$=value]
>
> Selecciona los elementos cuyo atributo attr cuyo valor tiene el sufijo
>   (seguido) de value.
>
> ### [attr*=value]
>
> Selecciona los elementos cuyo atributo attr tenga un valor que
>   contenga value.
>
> ### [attr operator value i]
>
> Agregar una i (o I) antes del corchete de cierre hace que el valor sea
>   comparado sin distinguir entre mayúsculas y minúsculas (para
>   caracteres dentro del rango ASCII).

En tu ejemplo, todos empiezan por `radio`, con lo que podrías usar como selector:

```
'input[name^="radio"]'
```

tanto en [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) como con el método `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: Entiendo pero los ejemplos son eso, ejemplos ya que los nombres de mis radios son todos diferentes y bueno, pensé que habría una forma más simplificada para hacer esto pero gracias por el aporte ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sí puedes, el selector sería similar a lo siguiente:

```
_$('input[name=radio1], input[name=radio2], input[name=radio3]');
```